# IntelliJ cannot resolve symbol 3rd party jar with Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a 3rd party JAR, which I've created an artifact for via the `mvn install:install-file` command. The artifact is added to the project, and the module's `pom.xml` and imported just fine.

Creating a Java class with a symbol from the 3rd party JAR, remains unresolved unfortunately. The red light bulb displays, and there's no option for "Import Class" as I would expect.

I've tried to Invalidate Caches | Restart but to no avail.

Any ideas?

*Edit* if I instead install the compiled JAR, the symbol is resolved. Why is this so?

*Edit 2* adding pom.xml displaying the internally shared artifact.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Sandbox</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
        <artifactId>third-party-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.x.y.z</groupId>
    <artifactId>thirdparty-z</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.x.y.thirdparty</groupId>
             <artifactId>thirdparty-sources</artifactId>
             <version>1.0</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.x.y.thirdparty</groupId>
             <artifactId>thirdparty-compiled</artifactId>
             <version>1.0</version>
         </dependency>
     </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Are the groupId, artifactId and version correct? (I mean are they the same you used when you installed the dependency?) Did you update the Maven project in IntelliJ?

Comment: Maybe "Maven - Download sources" will help, but not sure

Comment: the pom settings are fine, otherwise it wouldn't be imported into IntelliJ in the first place, right? I can navigate to the library and see the source. If I try to reference a class directly, like com.x.y.<ClassName> it doesn't work. IntelliJ is able to autocomplete com.x.y. but it doesn't display <Classname> in the dropdown, although it exists in the source jar!.

Comment: did you try mvn idea:idea

Comment: @awsome I don't import the project in that way. I only improt the pom.xml into IntelliJ.

Comment: Share your `pom.xml`, and if set up your `settings.xml`. Are you behind some http-proxy ? Sounds like the most basic set up is not working.

Comment: @Verhagen actually nothing fancy, I share with you what I can. The artifact is deployed to internal repo. Not behind any proxy, as I said the compiled dependency works just fine. But using the source dependency does not resolve the symbols in the .java file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Maven project file `pom.xml` contains the fixes, and some tips / hints about what is changed and why it has been changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!--  Parent POM best at the top  -->
    <!--  WANRING: Here you import the parent of 3th party. This is (almost) never correct!!!  -->
    <!--  For a simple project, which only exists of 1 set of classes and unit tests, you do   -->
    <!--  not need a parent POM. Only for multi module Maven project, you will have a parent   -->
    <!--  POM. Or for organisation wide configuration, of repositories, Maven plugin           -->
    <!--  configuration, and so. When starting with a small project, leave out the parent POM  -->
    <!--  reference.                                                                           -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
        <artifactId>third-party-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <!--  Better keep all project stuff together  -->
    <groupId>com.x.y.z</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-project-name</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>My Little Sandbox</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!--  Here only a reference to the compiled jar is required!!!                   -->
        <!--  If a source jar is available, it will get pulled in automatically!!!       -->
        <!--  As this is done by (naming) convention of all jars, in a Maven repository  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.x.y.thirdparty</groupId>
            <artifactId>thirdparty</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Remark:** The rare case where a new project extends a 3th party parent POM, is when the new project is some kind of extention / plug-in of the 3th party project. It then can use the same Maven Plug-in versions, dependecies, etc, etc, as the 3th party is using. Which makes it most lickly that the new *Extention / Plug-in* works well with the other parts, of the 3th party software.

*Concrete example to try*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.organisation.play-ground</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-little-sandbox</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>My Little Sandbox</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!--  A dependency reuired for each phase  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  A dependency only needed during runtime phase  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  A dependency only needed during compile and test phase  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: @hajder, did this bring you further?