# Maven extract jar, compile new with dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have a 3rd party jar with source files that I've added to my local repo. Now I want to extract it, compile it with it's dependencies, and finally package it into a new single jar.

I've completed the first step, by using the `maven-dependency-plugin`. It extracts the jar from the repo into `target/sources`.

How do I set the compiler phase to include that directory during compilation? I would expect it to generate errors at first, since it has other dependencies not in the `pom.xml` yet.

I've come across the assembly-plugin but I'm not sure if that would replace compiler-plugin?

Comment: It sounds like you want to bundle your app along with all its dependent jars files into a single jar.  Is that correct?  If so check out the Maven assembly plugin specifically the assembly:single goal.   These aren't really compile phase operations rather they are packaging phase operations.

Comment: Yes basically, but the odd part is that I think that I should compile the 3rd party source too. Because I'm having a problem with resolving the symbol in my IDE (IntelliJ). See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232710/intellij-cannot-resolve-symbol-3rd-party-jar-with-maven

Comment: You shouldn't need to compile the 3rd party source unless you need to change the source or you don't have the binaries for the library.  In either case the Maven way would be to build the 3rd party source into an artifact using its own pom.xml.  Then include that artifact as a dependency in your main projects pom.  Your source has no business residing in a subdirectory under target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q:** Why not get the compiled version (the jar, containing the compiled Java code (`*.class` files)) of the 3rd party library.

**Q:** Is the 3rd party, source code available from svn / git / etc?

**Q:** Does the source jar or the svn / git scm, contain a Maven `pom.xml` file, or Ant `build.xml`, or Gradle `build.gradle` ? Then use that to compile the code.

**About the Maven Plug-ins**

- The [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), is for creating archive files, like zip`,`*.tar.gz` etc.
- The [Maven Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/), is for compiling (Java) source code.

Comment: I'd like to have the source file for debugging purposes. Both compiled jar, and bundled jar are available. Neither contains any build file, like Maven or Ant though.

Comment: Normally you do not need to do anything with the source jar. When using Eclipse or IntelliJ, used create your project, add the compiled jars, and when using Maven, or Gradle to set up your own project, will automatically import the dependencies as compiled and source jars. Wear indeed the source jars are good for debugging.

Comment: See my comment above. Pasting again here:  odd part is that I think that I should compile the 3rd party source too. Because I'm having a problem with resolving the symbol in my IDE (IntelliJ). See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232710/intellij-cannot-resolve-symbol-3rd-party-jar-with-maven

Comment: @hajder this is the correct answer.  Key phrase here is compiled.  Do you have binaries (.class files) for the 3rd party software you are trying to use?  if not you have options.  1) include the lib's source in your project tree and compile it along with your source. 2) Treat the lib as a separate maven project and build it separately then add a dependency in your .pom file 3) find a binary distribution of the library and depend on that .jar.